# Problema al actualizar una tabla, Duplicate entry '19' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy intentando actualizar un carrito de compras luego de que usuarios se registra y asignándole el id del usuario a la tabla de carrito en una columna llamada cliente_id.
pero cuando termina la ejecución da un error `Duplicate entry '19' for key 'PRIMARY'` pero si se actualiza la base de datos, intente introducirlo en un if de php pero nada, creo q seria mejor un if de mysqli pero es algo avanzado para mis conocimientos.

Quería saber si me podrían echar una manita, Muchas Gracias!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$sql = "UPDATE carrito SET cliente_id = $cliente WHERE carrito_id = '$carrito'";
$db->query($sql);
```

Pruebas sin resultados positivos

```
// $sql = "UPDATE carrito SET cliente_id = $cliente WHERE carrito_id = '$carrito'";
// $sql = "UPDATE carrito IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM carrito carrito_id = '$carrito' )) SET cliente_id = $cliente";
// $sql = "UPDATE carrito SET cliente_id = $cliente WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM carrito WHERE carrito_id = '$carrito')";
// $sql = "UPDATE carrito SET IF NOT EXISTS cliente_id = $cliente WHERE carrito_id = '$carrito'";
```

Comment: Veo que estas actualizando el cliente_id, pero no deberia ser **UPDATE carrito SET carrito_id='$carrito' WHERE cliente_id='$cliente'**?

Comment: $carrito tiene un id único temporal por que aun el usuario no sea identificado,
luego cuando el usuario se registra o logea, el carrito tiene una columna llamada cliente_id en null que debe actualizarse cuando el usuario se identifica

Comment: Puedes colocar la estructura de tu tabla en la pregunta?

Comment: @JosueVargas actualizado el post con una imagen de esa tabla, en carrito quiero identificar el usuario cuando se registre

Comment: Te están pidiendo la estructura de la tabla, esto es, el esquema de definición, para saber  tus campos primary ley, y demás estructura.

Comment: @Jakala ahora si, gracias!!

Comment: con el grafico que has puesto, yo interpreto que el carrito tiene como clave una combinacion de campos (registroId, carritoId, productoId y cantidad). Si tienes que actualizar el cliente_id, entiendo que el WHERE debe incluir el resto de campos que forman la primaryKey de esa tabla no? Si no es asi, puedes añadir la definicion de la tabla? Puedes ejecutar la consulta "DESC carrito" para obtener esa definicion.